Firebase Cloud Functions internal server error when trying to curl URL with query parameters
I'm trying to pass some URL parameters to my cloud function and I keep facing an internal server error when I try to make a request. Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing it?
curl -X POST "https://testactivatelicense-a123bcdefg-uc.a.run.app/" -d license_key=3F9D04E3-F661-4F33-BB22-53FE83F111DC -d instance_name=test_1234 
Internal Server Error%

exports.testActivateLicense = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const licenseKey = request.query.license_key;
    const instanceName = request.query.instance_name;
    logger.log("Received request with licenseKey:", licenseKey, "and instanceName:", instanceName);

    const params = new URLSearchParams({license_key: licenseKey, instance_name: instanceName}).toString();
    logger.log("Constructed query parameters:", params);

    response.status(response.status).send(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    logAndSendError(error);
  }
});

function logAndSendError(error, res) {
  logger.error("Error occurred:", error.message);

  if (error.response) {
    logger.error("Error response status:", error.response.status);
    logger.error("Error response data:", JSON.stringify(error.response.data, null, 2));
    res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data);
  } else {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
}

function logAndSendError(error, res) {
  logger.error("Error occurred:", error.message);

  if (error.response) {
    logger.error("Error response status:", error.response.status);
    logger.error("Error response data:", JSON.stringify(error.response.data, null, 2));
    res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data);
  } else {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
}

Here is the logs from Google Cloud Logs Explorer:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
    at logAndSendError (/workspace/index.js:76:9)
    at /workspace/index.js:104:5
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/onInit.js:33:16
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:338:14)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/trace.js:18:37
    at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:98:17
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

UPDATE
I have fixed the above error, now I am facing a new issue, where it seems that my query parameters are not being passed to the function correctly. This is from the GCP Log Explorer:
Received request with licenseKey: undefined and instanceName: undefined

Constructed query parameters: license_key=undefined&instance_name=undefined

Here is my latest testActivateLicense for reference:
exports.testActivateLicense = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const licenseKey = request.query.license_key;
    const instanceName = request.query.instance_name;
    logger.log("Received request with licenseKey:", licenseKey, "and instanceName:", instanceName);

    const params = new URLSearchParams({license_key: licenseKey, instance_name: instanceName}).toString();
    logger.log("Constructed query parameters:", params);

    response.status(200).send("testActivateLicense completed successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    logAndSendError(error);
  }
});

UPDATE 2
I have fixed the above error by retrieving the license_key and instance_name with the following code instead:
const licenseKey = request.body.license_key;
const instanceName = request.body.instance_name;

UPDATE 3
Now I am attempting to actually validate the license using the lemonsqueezy validate endpoint. Here is my current version of  testActivateLicense:
exports.testActivateLicense = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const licenseKey = request.body.license_key;
    const instanceName = request.body.instance_name;
    logger.log("Received request with licenseKey:", licenseKey, "and instanceName:", instanceName);

    const params = new URLSearchParams({license_key: licenseKey, instance_name: instanceName}).toString();
    logger.log("Constructed query parameters:", params);

    logger.log("Making request to Lemonsqueezy API with URL:", validateUrl);
    const res = await axios.post(activateUrl, params, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${testApiKey}`,
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
      },
    });

    logger.log("Received response from Lemonsqueezy API with status:", res.status);
    logger.log("Response data:", JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2));
    response.status(res.status).send(res.data);
  } catch (error) {
    logAndSendError(error);
  }
});

And here are the logs I am getting:
Received request with licenseKey: ABCDEF-GHIJ-KLMN-OPQR-STUVWXYZ and instanceName: test_1234

Constructed query parameters: license_key=ABCDEF-GHIJ-KLMN-OPQR-STUVWXYZ&instance_name=test_1234

Making request to Lemonsqueezy API with URL: https://api.lemonsqueezy.com/v1/licenses/validate

Error: Error response data: {
  "message": "The license key field is required. (and 1 more error)",
  "errors": {
    "license_key": [
      "The license key field is required."
    ],
    "instance_name": [
      "The instance name field is required."
    ]
  }
}
    at entryFromArgs (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:130:19)
    at Object.error (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:116:11)
    at logAndSendError (/workspace/index.js:73:12)
    at /workspace/index.js:104:5
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Error: Error response status: 422
    at entryFromArgs (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:130:19)
    at Object.error (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:116:11)
    at logAndSendError (/workspace/index.js:72:12)
    at /workspace/index.js:104:5
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
    at logAndSendError (/workspace/index.js:74:9)
    at /workspace/index.js:104:5
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)



Internal Server Error means your function is crashing. Looking at your code, you use a response object never defined before. I'm not a rockstar in NodeJS, but it seems weird to me. maybe the source of your error. Have a look to the logs, you should have more details.

Are you sure you have the correct URL?  https://my.cloud.function.app/ doesn't look correct to me, as it's missing the name of the function in the URL.  The Firebase CLI should give you the fulll URL to use.  Also, are there any errors in the log?  Please edit the question to share those so we can see what the crash is.

Can you also log the values that you get in the request such as request.query along with the errors as Doug suggested?

@DougStevenson so the actual url is something like https://testactivatelicense-a123bcdefg-uc.a.run.app/
What I referenced in the question is just a placeholder

@Dharmaraj I have edited the question ton include the logs from GCP Logs Explorer.

Which line of code is line 76 (/workspace/index.js:76:9)? Also, I believe response.status(response.status) should take a number as an argument and not response.status itself.

@Dharmaraj I have update the question. You were correct, but now it appears that my query params are not being passed correctly to the function.

Can you please update your code to that latest version that you have remove the duplicate logAndSendError function? Your code still has request.query

UPDATE 4
To fix the issue in UPDATE 3, I have modified the way that the request parameters are retrieved. Here I am initially retrieving them from the query, and then they are retrieved from the body as well.
let licenseKey = request.query.license_key;
licenseKey = request.body.license_key ?? licenseKey;
let instanceName = request.query.instance_name;
instanceName = request.body.instance_name ?? instanceName;

